# Finding by id in Cassandra does not work

Tags: cassandra

I'm having a weird behavior with Cassandra. Whenever I try finding some rows by id, it returns me null (either by cqlsh console or clients), but the register exists if I find by another field.
For example:
[image]

My table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_aggregation_new.user_aggregation_new (
    userid timeuuid PRIMARY KEY,
    fullname text,
    birthdate text,
    password text,
    mobile text,
    address frozen <address>,
    thumbs map<text, text>,
    driverlicense frozen <driverlicense>,
    cpf text,
    facebookid text,
    membershipsince timestamp,
    rating double,
    email text,
    status text,
    facebookemail boolean,
    bankaccount list<frozen <bankaccount>>,
    dateupdated timestamp,
    version bigint
);
```

Cassandra version: 3.7

Why is this happening  ?

Comment: How many node do you have in each DC and what is your keyspace's RF and Class name ?

Comment: Change your default consistency level in cqlsh with below command:

cqlsh:test> CONSISTENCY; (check your default consistency level)
cqlsh:test> CONSISTENCY ALL ; (change it to ALL)
then check whether you get data by same query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options :

- Run **nodetool repair** on each node to improve data consistency
- Increase your client consistency level. In cqlsh, run the command **CONSISTENCY** with value **QUORUM** or **ALL**

Then retry and get back to us if it is still not working.

Comment: Are there any side effects on running **CONSISTENCY** ?? I'm kinda new to Cassadra, so some explanation on what will happen or may go wrong would be appreciated ! Thanks for your time

Comment: CONSISTENCY QUORUM is recommended. I think it should be the default value in cqlsh. CONSISTENCY ALL is stronger but not fault-tolerant. You should read [this](http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_config_consistency_c.html) to get in touch with Cassandra consistency model.

Comment: OK, I'll give QUORUM a try, gonna read more about it. Running nodetool repair seemed to resolve the issue. As soon as I'm 100% sure, I'll accept your answer. Thanks for all the info !

Comment: The repair did not work properly, some id's are still misbehaving. Think I'll give consistency a try to see if it helps.

Comment: Could you give us more info about number of nodes and replication strategy ? Could you run `nodetool status` ?